# The Web site SiteName does not contain a bin directory. Create a bin directory and try again

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

When I am trying to create a Web site in the AX 2012 Form I got the above error. I searched through the web but I am unable find a solution. I am attaching the screen shot.

In the URL place previously I have http://Website.com now I have changed it https://localhost/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif60/ but I didn't get any luck. Still having the same error.

[image: WebSiteConfiguration]

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the setup/configuration of your environment. Since this is not programming related, you should try another community to increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what the error says. It wants a `Bin` directory.

Create `C:\AIF\AIFin\Bin`. It's looking for the `Bin` folder.

See `\Data Dictionary\Tables\AifWebsites\Methods\validateWrite #21`